# Fetch all needed data from 2 different databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, model-view-controller, sqldatareader

[UPDATED]
I got a situation here where I need to fetch data from 2 different databases and then combine it into a model. I have an API method I made here that takes care of that but the moment I started working with a second database I got really confused on how I can retrieve more than one item. I'll explain. Here is the code to that method:

```
private List<FidelityModel> models;
public List<FidelityModel> getFidelityInfo2(string jobID) {
        FidelityModel fidelityInfo;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        string cjsJobName, ipwNumber, overnight, site;
        int packageCount;
        DateTime sla;
        models = new List<FidelityModel>();
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(@"server = [servername]; database = Dropoff; Integrated Security = true;")) {
            conn.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand("SELECT " +
                "[Job Name], " +
                "[Job ID], " +
                "[Package Count], " +
                "[Ship Method] " +
                "FROM [cjs_data] " +
                "WHERE [File Name] LIKE '%FDY%' AND [JOB ID] = @jobID", conn);
            command.Parameters.Add("@jobID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters["@jobID"].Value = jobID;
            //restructure to assign search results to string to later assign to model, as we will search again for SLA in a different database
            using (reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                if (reader.HasRows) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        fidelityInfo = new FidelityModel();
                        fidelityInfo.cjsJobName = reader.GetString(0);
                        fidelityInfo.ipwNumber = reader.GetString(1);
                        fidelityInfo.packageCount = reader.GetInt32(2);
                        if (fidelityInfo.cjsJobName.Contains("OVN")) { fidelityInfo.overnight = "Yes"; } else {
                            fidelityInfo.overnight = (reader.GetString(3).Equals("Overnight")) ? "Yes" : "No";
                        }
                        //site = (cjsJobName.Contains("EDG")) ? "EDGEWOOD" : "Other Site"; //not always the case
                        fidelityInfo.site = "EDGEWOOD";
                        models.Add(fidelityInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //How to incorporate this following block of code into the same model?
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(@"server = [servername]; database = MustMail; Integrated Security = true;")) {
            conn.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [SLA] FROM [Job] WHERE [JobID] = @jobID", conn);
            command.Parameters.Add("@jobID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters["@jobID"].Value = jobID;
            using (reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                if (reader.HasRows) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        //fidelityInfo.sla = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return models;
    }
```

As you can see right now I just have it working without fetching the SLA because I have no idea how to actually add the result I am fetching from the second database to the same model.

Comment: **WARNING:** Your SQL query is *wide open* to injection attacks. You *need* fix your application code and properly **parametrise** your statements. *Never* inject unsanitised values into your SQL queries.

Comment: Should I add the ID through Sqlcommand parameters in that case? @Larnu

Comment: Look into `Parameters.Add`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row in the DataReader create a new `FidelityModel` and add it to the list.  Something like:

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{
  var m = new FidelityModel()
  {
   cjsJobName = reader.GetString(0),
   ipwNumber = reader.GetString(1),
   packageCount = reader.GetInt32(2),
   sla = DateTime.Now
  };
  if (m.cjsJobName.Contains("OVN")) 
  { 
    m.overnight = "Yes"; 
  } 
  else 
  {
    m.overnight = (reader.GetString(3).Equals("Overnight")) ? "Yes" : "No";
  }
  models.Add(m);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that create a model that is going to lack SLA? I need to also get SLA in there that I obtain from a second database if you look further in the method and I need that information to also go in the same model. Or are you saying I should open reader.read loop and incorporate in it both connections?